# Define the order of terms in and logical operator

Tags: python, logical-operators

suppose that I have the two functions below:

```
def copy(src, dst) -> bool
    "copy src to dst return True if succeed else False"

def delete(src) -> bool
    "delete src return True if succeed else False"
```

src and dst can be complicated Objects, not just generic. the code is implemented correctly.

using those two functions I would like to implement move() function and return true if only both succeeded:

```
def move(src, dst) -> bool 
    return copy(src, dst) and delete(src)
```

the order of the terms in the and statement is important since I cannot delete src object before copying it.

is there any way of defining in the and (or any other logical operator) to do first the copying and then the deletion? does the order matters?

p.s: I know that I can do it like this:

```
def move(src, dst) -> bool 
    b1 = copy(src, dst)
    b2 = delete(src)
    return b1 and b2
```

but, I would like to do it as a one-liner as shown.

Comment: @MechanicPig What if `copy` or `delete` functions return `None`

Comment: `and` already works as you want, assuming both functions return truthy or falsey values…!?

Comment: @MechanicPig That’s the *opposite* of what OP wants. It’s also horribly unreadable.

Comment: @KonradRudolph This is not the opposite. I just mistakenly thought that OP wanted to avoid short circuit.

Comment: @MechanicPig I mean, it exactly inverts OP’s requirement (OP wants short-circuiting, their code already does short-circuiting, and your suggestion *specifically* removes short-circuiting). That sounds like the opposite to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`and` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) already evaluates arguments left-to-right. It's also a short-circuit operator i.e. it only evaluates the right argument if the left one is true (since if it was false then the expression would return false whatever the right argument is)

Answer (score 1):

I may have misunderstood you, but Python's `and` operator will shortcut the evaluation so that if you have `func1(action) and func2(action)` then `func2(action)` will only be called if `func1(action)` returns True. If it returns False, then `func2(action)` is not called.

Also, the functions are called in the order in which they appear in the `and` statement.

Example:

```
>>> def f1(action):
...     print(action)
...     return True
...
>>> def f2(action):
...     print(action)
...     return False
...
>>> f1("func1") and f2("func2")
func1
func2
False
>>> def f1(action):
...     print(action)
...     return False
...
>>> f1("func1") and f2("func2")
func1
False
```